# Gitlab : Spawning error : "File is a symlink that does not point to a valid file (RuntimeError)"

Tags: gitlab

Having a working gitlab instance on an Ubuntu 18.04 server for abouth 2 months, it now refuse to swpan due to the following 2 errors  in /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
App 14433 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: Cannot load database configuration:
App 14433 output: File "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/database.yml" is a symlink that does not point to a valid file (RuntimeError)
App 14433 output: Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/log/production.log exists and is writable (ie, make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/log/production.log). The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
```

The simlink exists and the file exists too :

```
ls /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config -als
0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    45 Dec  2 09:36 database.yml -> /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/database.yml

ls /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/ -als    
4 -rw-r----- 1 root git    525 Mar  2 14:39 database.yml


cat database.yml
# This file is managed by gitlab-ctl. Manual changes will be
# erased! To change the contents below, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
# and run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  collation: 
  database: gitlabhq_production
  pool: 1
  username: "gitlab"
  password: 
  host: "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql"
  ... ...
```

gitlab-ctl reconfigure is successfull, but application refuses to spawn...

Is it an issue of permissions  or user rights ?

The versions of the software are :

```
cat version-manifest.txt 
gitlab-ee 12.8.1

Component                      Installed Version                          Version GUID                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
acme-client                    2.0.5                                      
alertmanager                   v0.20.0                                    git:443fdb0b36de7b6a6cc4f7920ca559296c183b7b                              
awesome_print                  1.8.0                                      
bundler                        1.17.3                                     
bzip2                          1.0.6                                      md5:00b516f4704d4a7cb50a1d97e6e8e15b                                      
cacerts                        2019.01.23                                 md5:fccbe6cec7a76e3351ad32e305184787                                      
chef-acme                      5bd8e5c                                    git:c0f781dbce1718f73aa5f479b2aa55d6d501a95e                              
chef-gem                       14.14.29                                   
chef-zero                      14.0.13                                    
compat_resource                v12.19.1                                   git:e36200f6b804915b68a4ce74c8b7a293c041d9fe                              
config_guess                   c9092d05347c925a26f6887980e185206e13f9d6   git:5256817ace8493502ec88501a19e4051c2e220b0                              
consul                         v1.6.1                                     git:de366cc5a49ee409c7e62208de36e529fb4b9fea                              
curl                           curl-7_59_0                                git:4a90c5b82e21821496ef1afb5210a13f2564fcac                              
docker-distribution-pruner     v0.1.0                                     git:800e59b025e7376ae0dec92454b458bb504b9919                              
exiftool                       11.70                                      git:c6ca23d647608d16a702fce331a761e60d8708fe                              
git                            2.24.1                                     sha256:ad5334956301c86841eb1e5b1bb20884a6bad89a10a6762c958220c7cf64da02   
gitaly                         v12.8.1                                    git:61393768996e58bd5df436526cb46d5612ead584                              
gitlab-config-template         12.8.1                                     
gitlab-cookbooks               12.8.1                                     
gitlab-ctl                     12.8.1                                     
gitlab-ctl-ee                  12.8.1                                     
gitlab-elasticsearch-indexer   v2.1.0                                     git:1b9554a7e57adbe4e577ab36b85e6a5030b35961                              
gitlab-exporter                6.0.0                                      
gitlab-geo-psql                bc339ea21bdbb329263ad93788aaa428           
gitlab-healthcheck             90e6447aeead4a29ac9fffc15945ce6b           
gitlab-pages                   v1.16.0                                    git:6f4fcff22c468de4102d908455d5c01aa27b8760                              
gitlab-pg-ctl                  71f87e0dc829f288dfbec8991cc43675           
gitlab-psql                    7e11364159031db0eb55867ad3d5713b           
gitlab-rails                   v12.8.1-ee                                 git:13bae744d5c606ba83598a40a439abc340855b79                              
gitlab-scripts                 12.8.1                                     
gitlab-selinux                 12.8.1                                     
gitlab-shell                   v11.0.0                                    git:a7b6307397c0bf5414a102052042d405c3b40162                              
gitlab-workhorse               v8.21.0                                    git:9301e2ffe8e2ba63b6706899045603dc81b8917a                              
gnupg                          2.2.10                                     sha256:799dd37a86a1448732e339bd20440f4f5ee6e69755f6fd7a73ee8af30840c915   
go-crond                       0.6.1                                      git:8b21a6742dee4d2cfad54079f9b579a4efcd0ad6                              
gpgme                          1.10.0                                     sha256:1a8fed1197c3b99c35f403066bb344a26224d292afc048cfdfc4ccd5690a0693   
grafana                        6.3.5                                      sha256:0104bfe14444cea2fa3f021b9a75fc78f66434f2ca8f3d0bdd422d108ce682e7   
grafana-dashboards             v1.3.0                                     git:a732bbba52bd21f7e30ea3b0aa4372228f20b229                              
graphicsmagick                 1.3.34                                     sha256:4717f7a32d964c515d83706fd52d34e089c2ffa35f8fbf43c923ce19343cf2f4   
jemalloc                       5.2.1                                      git:2abb02ecd74e7e65d3992a542ffb43abe91a8a7f                              
krb5                           krb5-1.17                                  git:fcfb0e47c995a7e9f956c3716be3175f44ad26e0                              
libassuan                      2.5.1                                      sha256:47f96c37b4f2aac289f0bc1bacfa8bd8b4b209a488d3d15e2229cb6cc9b26449   
libedit                        20120601-3.0                               md5:e50f6a7afb4de00c81650f7b1a0f5aea                                      
libevent                       release-2.1.8-stable                       git:6f970267b6ba68c9dd9090d789c928529745dc68                              
libffi                         3.2.1                                      md5:83b89587607e3eb65c70d361f13bab43                                      
libgcrypt                      1.8.3                                      sha256:66ec90be036747602f2b48f98312361a9180c97c68a690a5f376fa0f67d0af7c   
libgpg-error                   1.32                                       sha256:c345c5e73cc2332f8d50db84a2280abfb1d8f6d4f1858b9daa30404db44540ca   
libiconv                       1.15                                       sha256:ccf536620a45458d26ba83887a983b96827001e92a13847b45e4925cc8913178   
libicu                         release-57-1                               git:b772241b52fcec07b1909d44d156fbcd0cbfb20c                              
libksba                        1.3.5                                      sha256:41444fd7a6ff73a79ad9728f985e71c9ba8cd3e5e53358e70d5f066d35c1a340   
liblzma                        5.2.4                                      sha256:b512f3b726d3b37b6dc4c8570e137b9311e7552e8ccbab4d39d47ce5f4177145   
libossp-uuid                   1.6.2                                      md5:5db0d43a9022a6ebbbc25337ae28942f                                      
libpng                         v1.6.37                                    git:301f7a14295a3bdfaf406dbb5004d0784dc137ea                              
libre2                         2016-02-01                                 git:5bd613749fd530b576b890283bfb6bc6ea6246cb                              
libtool                        2.4.6                                      sha256:e3bd4d5d3d025a36c21dd6af7ea818a2afcd4dfc1ea5a17b39d7854bcd0c06e3   
libxml2                        2.9.9                                      md5:c04a5a0a042eaa157e8e8c9eabe76bd6                                      
libxslt                        1.1.32                                     md5:1fc72f98e98bf4443f1651165f3aa146                                      
libyaml                        0.1.7                                      sha256:8088e457264a98ba451a90b8661fcb4f9d6f478f7265d48322a196cec2480729   
logrotate                      3.15.1                                     git:1e125a3a03597d195b9f3daddc099236c5c10782                              
mattermost                     5.19.1                                     md5:92be732bd5382dabae970b437769eb0d                                      
mixlib-log                     3.0.1                                      
ncurses                        5.9                                        md5:8cb9c412e5f2d96bc6f459aa8c6282a1                                      
nginx                          1.16.1                                     sha256:f11c2a6dd1d3515736f0324857957db2de98be862461b5a542a3ac6188dbe32b   
nginx-module-vts               v0.1.18                                    git:46d85558e344dfe2b078ce757fd36c69a1ec2dd3                              
node-exporter                  v0.18.1                                    git:ef7c05816adcb0e8923defe34e97f6afcce0a939                              
npth                           1.6                                        sha256:1393abd9adcf0762d34798dc34fdcf4d0d22a8410721e76f1e3afcd1daa4e2d1   
ohai                           14.14.0                                    
omnibus-ctl                    1b96ac486636cac987e5b464810bb3ff673a93fe   git:e160156deaa0afc037748b10d1c9ef0a5be97dc1                              
openssl                        OpenSSL_1_1_1d                             git:e1182bdb8a735b96dd99d8eefd01e4edf6241a82                              
package-scripts                12.8.1+ee.0                                
pcre                           8.42                                       md5:fc18afa0f14a25475cf097ee102a3e4f                                      
pcre2                          10.31                                      md5:10e1a95a0f0d80759f1b3d70e92c2cda                                      
pgbouncer                      1.12.0                                     sha256:1b3c6564376cafa0da98df3520f0e932bb2aebaf9a95ca5b9fa461e9eb7b273e   
pgbouncer-exporter             v0.1.2-gitlab                              git:a4349da2b62c53cbd2b8db152b5dce431160c7d4                              
pkg-config-lite                0.28-1                                     md5:61f05feb6bab0a6bbfab4b6e3b2f44b6                                      
popt                           1.16                                       md5:3743beefa3dd6247a73f8f7a32c14c33                                      
postgres-exporter              v0.8.0                                     git:aeec47ead4ad3941cf1b6588b1ac5a44ca9e9c4b                              
postgresql                     10.12                                      sha256:388f7f888c4fbcbdf424ec2bce52535195b426010b720af7bea767e23e594ae7   
postgresql_new                 11.7                                       sha256:324ae93a8846fbb6a25d562d271bc441ffa8794654c5b2839384834de220a313   
postgresql_old                 9.6.17                                     sha256:f6e1e32d32545f97c066f3c19f4d58dfab1205c01252cf85c5c92294ace1a0c2   
prometheus                     v2.13.1                                    git:687a962bd19be4d39c9a4ba38d7167e5cd6c0942                              
python-docutils                0.13.1                                     
python3                        3.7.3                                      sha256:d62e3015f2f89c970ac52343976b406694931742fbde2fed8d1ce8ebb4e1f8ff   
rb-readline                    master                                     git:9fba246073f78831b7c7129c76cc07d8476a8892                              
redis                          5.0.7                                      git:3c610b4e8d8d4b09254c5e1a435ca25b82710e38                              
redis-exporter                 v1.3.5                                     git:95d0b33be7f03502e1829c18429ee8c31fdbcbcc                              
registry                       v2.8.1-gitlab                              git:ae2e973db9365d6f8401ffb6bfc603f3cd76b111                              
remote-syslog                  1.6.15                                     
repmgr                         v3.3.2                                     git:0141bc2be70dbf7427f09fcc8ea2d3dfe60c1be5                              
repmgr_pg_10                   v3.3.2                                     git:eaee7145f652852aabfd20c53c3a40cd8accdfcc                              
repmgr_pg_11                   v3.3.2                                     git:eaee7145f652852aabfd20c53c3a40cd8accdfcc                              
rsync                          3.1.3                                      md5:1581a588fde9d89f6bc6201e8129afaf                                      
ruby                           2.6.5                                      sha256:66976b716ecc1fd34f9b7c3c2b07bbd37631815377a2e3e85a5b194cfdcbed7d   
rubygems                       2.7.10                                     
runit                          2.1.2                                      md5:6c985fbfe3a34608eb3c53dc719172c4                                      
unzip                          6.0                                        sha256:036d96991646d0449ed0aa952e4fbe21b476ce994abc276e49d30e686708bd37   
version-manifest               0.0.1                                      
zlib                           v1.2.11                                    git:cacf7f1d4e3d44d871b605da3b647f07d718623f
```

Comment: Do a `chmod 644 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/database.yml` and see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks for helping. This didn't change anything. The file is there but maybe groups are wrong ?

Comment: It's tough to say. It will be a permission issue only, but why it happened in first place is big question. Unfortunately can't recommend something more remotely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly a permissions error.

Make sure that whatever file is readable: `chmod a+r /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/database.yml` (according to the comments you already did this) AND

Make sure that all the directories are *executable*, which for directories allows cd'ing into that directory:

```
chmod a+x /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config
chmod a+x /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/log
chmod a+x /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/
chmod a+x /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/
chmod a+x /opt/gitlab/embedded/
chmod a+x /opt/gitlab/
chmod a+x /opt/
```

Note that this is just a (possibly insecure) example, but should work.

I would also check to make sure the ruby process is running as the `git` user as you expect.

Comment: I changed a lot of things, inclung user stuff to run rails anc access directories. I am not sure this is the thing taht sole my issue but anyway, you took the time to read, help and propose ideas, so I am glad to accept the answer and give the bounty ;-) Thx